# How to make the menu contents center aligned?

Tags: html, css, menu, center

I want to make the menu contents center aligned.
I have 2 files: index.html and style.css

**HTML** [index.html]:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="header">
  <h1 id="logo">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentHeader"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
    <div class="contentBody"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentHeader"> Where does it come from? </div>
      <div class="contentBody"> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentHeader"> Where do we use it? </div>
      <div class="contentBody"> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentHeader"> Where do we use it? </div>
      <div class="contentBody"> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** [style.css]:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

a:hover { background-color: #16a085; }

li {
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#menu {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 50px;
}

#container { position: relative; }

#logo {
    font-family: arial;
    color: #3498db;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.right {
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #2980b9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 160px;
}

.left {
    width: 34%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 160px;
}

.clear { clear: both; }

.content { margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px; }

.contentHeader {
    font-family: impact;
    color: #bdc3c7;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contentBody {
    font-family: arial;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.center {
    width: 38%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 560px;
}
```

How can I make the menu items appear at the center? It is now appearing in the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
text-align:center;

}



li
{
font-family:arial;
font-size:20px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Remove `float:left` and add `text-align:center` and `display:inline-block`

[Working: jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QA2J/)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution-1**

Add these two properties to your css.

[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/4H55e/)

```
#menu
{
text-align:center;
}

ul{
display:inline-block;
}
```

**Solution-2**

Add this property to your `ul` :

[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/4H55e/1/)

```
ul{
display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the `ul` within the `menu` div a fixed width, you can apply `margin:0 auto;`

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="centerMargin">
```

CSS

```
.centerMargin
{
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Why was mine given a negative vote? It is correct =/ Here is a JSFiddle of HIS EXACT CODE with my fix in : http://jsfiddle.net/cMLQs/

Answer (score 0):

Just give `display: -webkit-flex` to the `#menu`

Working Code:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/L29AH/3/)

Using the above property depends on the browser.if you are using mozilla you will have to add 
`display: -moz-flex`

Answer (score -1):

remove this line:

```
li {float:left}
```